# Show Heroku Logs. I use CarrierWave + S3 + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I need show the heroku logs but I send "heroku logs" and I get a error, "Could not connect to logging service".

I'm using CarrierWave in my App. The app is perfect in my localhost but in heroku doesn't work.. "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

I need show logs! =/

I followed an example to use carrierwave + S3 + Heroku... I need help.

thx

Comment: If you want to show the `heroku logs` just do in the console `heroku logs` and this will produce this for you. Also I believe you should take a look at this which may be a useful to you https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku</a>

Comment: Thx. But heroku logs return "Could not connect to logging service"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of firewall prevents accessing to various heroku domains?  Or blocking port 443?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

`heroku logs --app APP_NAME_HERE`

otherwise run a restart and try again. Add the --app part if you need to.

`heroku restart`

`heroku logs`